# Pi3 Rainbow screen + only red LED

Tags: boot, sd-card, boot-issues

I've just got my first Pi 3 and after powering it on it stuck on Rainbow screen aka Coloured splash screen and only red LED is lighting.

I've tried:

- multiple power supplies (5V @ 2.1A and 5V @3.1A) and USB cables
- several microSD cards
- both recent NOOBS and Raspbian (on Windows and Linux machines following all installation guidelines)
- checked files checksum
- tried `boot_delay=1` solution
- eject'ed SD cards

I don't have another Pi to check my SDcards.

Any thoughts on what can I do?

**EDIT:**
output of `fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0` is below:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 14.9 GiB, 15931539456 bytes, 31116288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd94ffdb3

Device         Boot  Start     End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192  137215  129024  63M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      137216 8493055 8355840   4G 83 Linux
```

Comment: *"I don't have another Pi to check my SDcards."* -> Obviously enough you can check them on linux, and you refer to having a "linux machine" into which you can put SD cards.  Do it and edit in the output from `fdisk -l /dev/whatever`, where `whatever` is the whole device, not a partition.

Comment: Sadly.. maybe your Pi is dead ;( Make sure you do not plug anything into the USB ports. Just plug in HDMI and power and SD card. If it doesnt come out of rainbow Pi then I really suspect there is a problem with the hardware ;(

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. fdisk output is attached, powering on with only plugged monitor made no effect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case someone is interested: that Pi3 was delivered broken.

Successfully replaced and running.